# sed: Search and Replace string that conforms to a specific regular expression

Tags: sed

Using sed, I am attempting to recursively search and replace a string `foo` that may have characters before it as well as after it.

For examples:-

```
"foo_

'foo_abc
```

I want to specifically replace `foo` with `foobar` so that my example above will become:-

```
"foobar_

'foobar_abc
```

I am not succeeding with:-

```
find . -name "*.py" | xargs sed -i '/*foo*/{s/foo/foobar/g}'
```

What should I do instead to search and replace successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `*`'s should do, and you don't need the initial `/foo/`:

```
find . -name "*.py" | xargs sed -i 's/foo/foobar/g'
```

Comment: O yes. you are right. I got confused because some strings are actually in `.html` files and I was only replacing stuff in my `.py` files. My bad.